# Android development Array comparing with int

Tags: java, android, arrays, int

Beginner in Android development.
My code crashes. I have made a simple Java method like a inArray function in php.

```
private ArrayList<Long> inArray(int array[], int searched)
{
    ArrayList<Long> ans = new ArrayList<Long>();

    for(int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)
    {
          if (array[i] == searched)
          {
              ans.add((long) i);
          }
    } 

    return ans;
}
```

It doesn't work on this stage

```
if (array[i] == searched)
```

How can i Compare them ? I have tried many things but the code just keeps crashing.
Thank you very much.

Comment: use i < array.length instead of i <= array.length

Comment: Cant believe that this little peace of .... was the problem. Interesting why ? Will look in to it. Thank you very much.

Comment: array.length returns the number of elements. In a 10 element array, it returns 10, while the elements are 0-9. When it gets to 10, it crashes with an arrayOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: your problem get solved or not? problem is because you are using i=0 and looping to length-1

Comment: my problem got solved Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
for(int i = 0; i <array.length; i++)
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i <= array.length-1; i++)
```

instead of

```
for(int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)
```